# Basic syntax explanation for variables in bashrc

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, variable

I want to correctly export a variable.  In order to do so I have to understand several variations in syntax.  I've seen the following mechanisms of exporting a variable.  In this case I am using `.bashrc`:

1. `export MY_VARIABLE=$USER/.gradle` --$
2. `export MY_VARIABLE="$USER/.gradle"` --Quotes
3. `export MY_VARIABLE=USER/.gradle` --No $
4. `export $MY_VARIABLE=$USER/.gradle` --All the $

What is the significance of the $ sign in these cases?  Why is it sometimes used and other times not?

Do we need quotes in cases where there are no spaces in the path?  What if the path is contained in $USER contains spaces?

Why no $ on the left hand side of export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokens such as `export`, `declare`, and the like explicitly use variable names as parameters.  `$` can generally be understood to mean "the value of", so `$variable` means "the value of `variable`".  Take this set of commands:

```
foo=bar
bar=baz
export $foo
( echo "$foo" )
```

What will happen here is that you will get one blank line of output.  This is because in the `export` command, `$foo` is actually `bar` (the value of `foo`), so the actual command executed is `export bar`.  Since `foo` is not exported, its default value is null.  However, if the last line were:

```
( echo "$bar" )
```

You would get the output of `baz`, the value of `bar` which had been `export`ed into forthcoming subshells.

It is generally a very good idea to use weak quotes ("`"`") around *all* of your variable references, for reasons including but not limited to the one you mention (i. e. spaces in filenames and paths).  For example, if we had:

```
if [ $letter == a ]; then echo "ayyyy"; fi
```

but `letter` were empty, the shell would attempt to execute

```
if [  == a ]
```

which is a syntax error, but with quotes:

```
if [ "$letter" == a ];
```

becomes

```
if [ "" == a ];
```

which is valid.

Comment: Would point out that you are doing two things with the `export` statement: first is "assignment" of a value to the variable and the second is "exporting" of that value to the process (and all child processes). See also http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/variables.html

Comment: True.  Though I habitually give all my variables values first and export them separately.